# Cassandra sstableloader failed on loading a table snapshot "Cannot connect"

Tags: cassandra, connection

using sstableloader load a new table from a keyspace snapshot on a different cluster, have an error

Steps to recreate:

1. create this table
2. cp snapshot files to a temp directory temp_dir.
3. sstableloader load ( error out )

Anybody know what the problem is? How can I fix it? Thank you.

Detail like :

```
sstableloader --nodes vm_cdb01 -u dba -p xxx /xxx/temp_dir/snapshot_directory
WARN  21:21:42,124 Small cdc volume detected at /cdc_raw; setting cdc_total_space_in_mb to 1773.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  21:21:42,302 Only 45.202GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: vm-cdb01/10.28.60.76:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [vm-cdb01/xx.xxx.76] Cannot connect))
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: vm-cdb01/xx.xxx.76:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [vm-cdb01/xx.xxx.76] Cannot connect))
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:233)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1424)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:163)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:334)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:309)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:251)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeSSTableLoaderClient.init(NativeSSTableLoaderClient.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:80)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:48)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: vm-cdb01/xx.xxx.76:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [vm-cdb01/xx.xxx.76] Cannot connect))
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:93)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:48)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: vm-cdb01/xx.xxx.76:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [vm-cdb01/xx.xxx.76] Cannot connect))
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:233)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1424)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:163)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:334)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:309)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:251)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeSSTableLoaderClient.init(NativeSSTableLoaderClient.java:73)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:159)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:80)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem is I used a wrong ip. can not use `hostname -s` our node has management ip and private ip.

Answer (score 0):

How anyone thought sstableloader was easy enough to run, to me, seemed quite ridiculous. It makes assumptions that should be covered by program switches. It has been a while since I have run sstableloader, but because of how it works, I ended up creating a shell script to do the work - especially if you wanted to copy, say, multiple tables from multiple keyspaces to different locations. At a high level, here is how my script runs the command:

sstableloader -u ${targetUser} -pw ${cassandraCopyTargetPassword} -d ${targetHost} `pwd`

Everything you supply is for the target. If you are running on a different port than the default, you'll need to specify "-p ####". I've noticed you have something "off" for your "-p" (port) value - like a directory path.

Now as for what it's actually loading, that's where I think the entire process falls apart - and someone should address it as it's ridiculous what the assumptions are (again, instead of switches).

sstableloader looks which directory you're in - that has to directly match up with the keyspace and table you're TARGET table will reside.

For example, on the source, let's assume I want to copy all of sstables from, say, the /opt/cassandra/data/sourceKeyspace/sourceTable directory BUT that would be mapped to the targetKeyspace/targetTable on the TARGET system. I would need to create the directory that matches the targetKeyspace/targetTable somewhere on the source host. For example, I could create that directory as /tmp/targetKeyspace/targetTable (it doesn't have to be in /tmp, but it's as good of a place as any). I would then change directories to that location, create soft links from that directory to all of the sstables in the /opt/cassandra/data/sourceKeyspace/sourceTable) and run the sstableloader supplying the name of the target directory created above (or pwd if you're sitting in the target directory, as I do with my script). Confusing to say the least.

Again, the idea that this was a good idea on how to make it work is beyond me. Anyway, hopefully this helps you get it working.

Comment: I often describe sstableloader as a tool brought to us by aliens...